# Split logic in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am looking for an sql query which would take the following table data as input

```
ID  Start date  end date

ID1 01.01.2016  31.12.2016

ID2 01.02.2016  30.06.2016

ID3 01.10.2016  31.10.2016

ID4 01.02.2016  31.07.2016
```

and gives the following output

```
ID1 01.01.2016  31.01.2016

ID4 01.02.2016  31.07.2016

ID1 01.08.2016  30.09.2016

ID3 01.10.2016  31.10.2016

ID1 01.11.2016  31.12.2016
```

please see that ID1 is split for only one month as ID2,ID3 and ID4 has an overlap with ID1.
The idea is the latest date range gets the preference. if you see the output ID2 is completly rejected as it is overwritten by ID4.

please can you post the hints of the query.

Comment: I see no code showing your attempts at this? Please share code and review the following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Also, your _tags_ you've used, which DBMS do you require this query for? Tags in StackOverflow are not like hashtags in social media - by adding more, doesn't mean you'll get more responses to your question. Remove the ones that do not apply.

Comment: ID1 is the initial plan and ID2 is the change (or update of ID1) and so on.. so the plan table which is the input holds all the changes in terms of plans with IDs.  with the changes introduced i would like to see the overlapping date ranges which can invalidate the previous plan and also split the records as shown in the output result.  sorry for less explanation

Comment: update your question with schema info and sql queries you have used to to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought up some logic for doing this.  I can give the syntax for sql server (but you would have to find the syntax for mysql).  Replace [Table Name] with the name of your table in the queries that follow.

Get the maximum end date from your table and store in a variable:

```
declare @max_end_date datetime
set @max_end_date = (select max([end date]) from [Table Name])
```

Collect possible start dates into a temporary table, adding in a row number and two blank columns (' ' as id, 0 as dupe):

```
select
  row_number()over(order by start_date) as row,
  start_date,
  '' as id,
  0 as dupe
into #temp
from
  (select [start date] as start_date
  from [Table Name]
  union
  select dateadd(day,1,[end date])
  from [Table Name]
  where [end date] <> @max_end_date )
group by start_date
```

Update each row of the temporary table with the plan effective on that start date:

```
update #temp
set #temp.id = c.id
from #temp
left outer join 
  (select a.start_date, max(b.id) as id
  from #temp a
  inner join [Table Name] b
    on a.start_date between b.[start date] and b.[end date]
  group by a.start_date) c
on #temp.start_date = c.start_date
```

Update the temporary table with a flag to mark out 'duplicate' rows:

```
update #temp
set #temp.dupe = 1
from #temp
inner join #temp b
on a.row = b.row + 1
and a.id = b.id
```

Delete the duplicate rows:

```
delete from #temp where dupe = 1
```

Update the row column:

```
update #temp
set row = row_number()over(order by start_date)
```

Join this table to itself to create the table you are after:

```
select 
  a.id as id, 
  a.start_date as start_date,
  isnull(dateadd(day,-1,b.start_date),@max_end_date) as end_date
from #temp a
left outer join #temp b
  on a.row = b.row - 1
```

Comment: Given that I spent ages doing this solution in a desperate attempt to get some reputation so that I can, in turn, attract some bounty hunters to my questions, I decided to adapt this code to Postgres to see if it worked. With the exception of one missing line in the code (now added to the solution above), it did.

Comment: Thanks @vorpulus. i will verify and comeback